# Hashmap in UML diagram?

Tags: hashmap, uml, class-diagram

I want to write a class diagram for a class that contains a hashmap. 
Normally, I would do this:

[image]

But my Map looks like this:

`private Map<Beacon, String> beaconRoute;`

The key is a custom class.

How can I describe it in an UML diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `beacon : Beacon` inside the qualifier rectangle and use the `String` data type as the target type (instead of `Employee`). The property `beaconRoute` is the association end name. You don't have to be so literal as to have a Map class in UML--doing that loses sight of the problem domain. Not that I understand why a `Beacon` would map to a `String`, though. Did you reverse the key and value by mistake?

Comment: Thanks :)
No, that was not a mistake. Maybe it would have been better to create a class that contains a Beacon and a String.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an association class for that:

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is a separate BeaconRoute class. He said the key is a custom class.